# Custom validation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have `EmailValidator` class inside module like:

```
module ActiveModel
  module Validations
    class EmailValidator < EachValidator
      def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
        if value.presence && (value =~ /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/).nil?
          record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid")
        end
      rescue => e
        record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to use this inside my model but facing load error when I try to start rails server => **email_validator.rb** to define `EmailValidator` (*LoadError*)

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is this module in a file called `email_validator.rb` ?

Comment: yes. this file is in lib/active_model/validations/email_validator.rb

Comment: have this  `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
`  on application.rb?

Comment: I do have this configuration settings in application.rb

Comment: Why put this in a module? I have put this in a app/validators folder, but simply defining the class, without any modules around it

Comment: I have folder structure like that means, ROOT/lib/active_model/validations/email_validator.rb

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [the `valid_email` gem](https://github.com/hallelujah/valid_email) instead, because validating email adresses is a real pain!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true

  # ...
end
```

Also see [this humongous regular expression](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) which actually validates email addresses according to RFC 822.

Comment: I am using active resource. 
Is there any way you can use do email validation without using gem and keep the code DRY as well.

Answer (score 0):

validates_format_of :email, :with =>~ /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]+\z/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this kind of syntax and implement your code according this  [blog](http://my.rails-royce.org/2010/07/21/email-validation-in-ruby-on-rails-without-regexp/) that should be very helpful:-

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.presence && (value =~ /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/).nil?
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid")
    end
  rescue => e
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid")
  end
end
```

just put this file in app/validators/email_validator.rb

for rails 3 custom validation please [read](http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3/) this blog.

**In Rails 4**

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
  end
 end
end

class foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, email: true
end
```

At last very simple and dry use reg. exp.:-

```
/\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/
```

That was adapted from http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html